# What is the full list of provider id's for firebase.UserInfo.providerId?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The docs say

> For example, 'facebook.com', or 'google.com'.

However, is the exhaustive list available somewhere and can I depend on it? Can these id's ever be a variation, like 'facebook' or 'google' (without the .com)?

Context: I am trying to figure out if the signed in user has a social login. So I want to loop through `currentUser.providerData` and match it against a known list of providerIds.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

From the Sign-In Method sub-tab within Authentication found on the Firebase console for any project, you can see a list of available Sign-in providers:

[image]

Firebase's documentation doesn't seem to be even across different platforms, but for the [iOS Reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Constants) there is a list of FirebaseAuth Constants that match up with those from the project console dashboard, with the exception of Anonymous provider:

1. EmailAuthProviderID
2. PhoneAuthProviderID
3. GoogleAuthProviderID
4. FacebookAuthProviderID
5. TwitterAuthProviderID
6. GitHubAuthProviderID
7. AppleAuthProviderID
8. YahooAuthProviderID
9. MicrosoftAuthProviderID

After making a new iOS project from scratch and adding this code to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
print("EmailAuthProviderID: " + EmailAuthProviderID)
print("PhoneAuthProviderID: " + PhoneAuthProviderID)
print("GoogleAuthProviderID: " + GoogleAuthProviderID)
print("FacebookAuthProviderID: " + FacebookAuthProviderID)
print("TwitterAuthProviderID: " + TwitterAuthProviderID)
print("GitHubAuthProviderID: " + GitHubAuthProviderID)
print("AppleAuthProviderID: " + AppleAuthProviderID)
print("YahooAuthProviderID: " + YahooAuthProviderID)
print("MicrosoftAuthProviderID: " + MicrosoftAuthProviderID)
```

The output I get is:

```
EmailAuthProviderID: password
PhoneAuthProviderID: phone
GoogleAuthProviderID: google.com
FacebookAuthProviderID: facebook.com
TwitterAuthProviderID: twitter.com
GitHubAuthProviderID: github.com
AppleAuthProviderID: apple.com
YahooAuthProviderID: yahoo.com
MicrosoftAuthProviderID: hotmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks Pat. Good research! This is very helpful.

Comment: I just stopped by to say you are the best, Pat! This answer is more helpful and useful than you can ever realize.

Comment: Thank you @Joris Mans for keeping this list up to date!

Comment: I know this is has been anwered long ago, but the SDK source gives you a list of the constants - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseAuth/Sources/AuthProvider/FIRAuthProvider.m - this way you can find the current string literals without having to run anything.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest way is to check the providers list in the rules tab:
[image: Auth providers list]

Answer (score 4):

you can use this method to identify the Type of Provider :

```
    private String checkType(String s) {
    String type;

    switch (s) {
        case "password":
            type = "EmailAuthProviderID";
            break;
        case "phone":
            type = "PhoneAuthProviderID";
            break;
        case "google.com":
            type = "GoogleAuthProviderID";
            break;
        case "facebook.com":
            type = "FacebookAuthProviderID";
            break;
        case "twitter.com":
            type = "TwitterAuthProviderID";
            break;
        case "github.com":
            type = "GitHubAuthProviderID";
            break;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    import com.google.firebase.auth.*


    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    user?.let {
        for (profile in it.providerData) {
            when(profile.providerId){
                GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> {

                }
                EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> {

                }
                PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> {

                }
                FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> {

                }
                TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> {

                }
                GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are Firebase SDK provider classes.

Answer (score 0):

Strange is MicrosoftAuthProvider is missing on [js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth) (but works) and available on unity SDK