# How to determine if the user has signed up using email in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I already did a Google Sign check. But I don't know how to realize email check.

```
for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
            if (user.getProviderId().equals("google.com")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }else if (user.getEmail().equals("email")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901153/what-is-the-full-list-of-provider-ids-for-firebase-userinfo-providerid

Answer (score 0):

If  you have multiple authentication mechanisms, then you should use FirebaseAuth's [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) method:

> Returns a list of signin methods that can be used to sign in a given user (identified by its main email address). This will match the [getSignInMethod()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential#getSignInMethod()) for the credential you would generate for the appropriate signin mechanism.
>
> This method is useful when you support multiple authentication mechanisms if you want to implement an email-first authentication flow. It is also useful to resolve a [FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.html) thrown on [signInWithCredential(AuthCredential)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)).