# Firebase + Flutter : get platform user used to sign in

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, dart

I have an app with 3 sign in methods: Google, Facebook & mail.
I want to show the users that are signed in with mail a different screen. 
Is it possible to get the sign in method form the package firebase authentication?

I know I can fix this by using firestore & checking if a statement is true or false. But that will cost me a read every time a user opens the app...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be what you want: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderData()

In my app where I use Google logins only, I have `firebaseUser.providerData[1].providerId == 'google.com'`.

Btw, `firebaseUser.providerData[0].providerId == 'firebase'`.

I guess you could check them all and look for what providers you get for different kinds of users.

Edit: here's what I get when logging in with e-mail: https://postimg.cc/BXWGGN6h

Comment: Thanks! So what should I use for checking if user used mail?

Comment: Currently I'm not getting 'firebase' at index 0. It just shows 'google.com' etc.
Thank you by the way. Hard way to get info on a surprisingly underdocumented feature. I guess they could just mention this at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#reauthenticating-a-user

Answer (score 15):

Firebase has a special property `providerId`. But, as mentioned @GazihanAlankus it always returns `firebase`.

And, the property `firebaseUser.providerData[1].providerId` sometimes not exists (for example when user used anonymous login).

So, we should use appropriate approaches, for example:

```
FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();

if (user.providerData.length < 2) {
  // do something
}
else {
  print(res.providerId);  
}
```

The list of values, that are returned by property `providerId`:

```
EmailAuthProviderID: password
PhoneAuthProviderID: phone
GoogleAuthProviderID: google.com
FacebookAuthProviderID: facebook.com
TwitterAuthProviderID: twitter.com
GitHubAuthProviderID: github.com
AppleAuthProviderID: apple.com
YahooAuthProviderID: yahoo.com
MicrosoftAuthProviderID: hotmail.com
```

I got this list from the cool research here [What is the full list of provider id's for firebase.UserInfo.providerId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901153/what-is-the-full-list-of-provider-ids-for-firebase-userinfo-providerid)

Answer (score 1):

In my app I used
`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.providerData[0].providerId == 'google.com'.`,
cause providerData[1] doesn't contain any value

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30702359)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in 2022, Firebase now has nice new docs for Flutter and in it they have this, which I personally found super useful:

```
if (user != null) {
    for (final providerProfile in user.providerData) {
        // ID of the provider (google.com, apple.cpm, etc.)
        final provider = providerProfile.providerId;

        // UID specific to the provider
        final uid = providerProfile.uid;

        // Name, email address, and profile photo URL
        final name = providerProfile.displayName;
        final emailAddress = providerProfile.email;
        final profilePhoto = providerProfile.photoURL;
    }
}
```

Source: [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information)

Answer (score -1):

**But that will cost me a read every time a user opens the app.** THIS IS TRUTH!

Alternatively, you can create your own app DB using [SQFLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), and create only one table `(user)` in that, having a field of `signUpMethod` having possible values are `google, facebook and mail`. Whenever you opens the app, first check that in your db, if this is `mail`, redirect to another screen which you want, else call `firebase service`

Cheers!