# How to know if the user is signed in with Google or Facebook in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know there is the `User.providerData` getter for all the providers the user with a specific email address logged in. But I want to know the provider used for the current session! Is the `User.providerData` list sorted in the order of providers linked/or signed in? I don't think so, because an email address can be used with a Google provider, then with Facebook provider, in which case, if we assume the list is sorted by the providers linked, the list will be `[Google, Facebook]`. But if the user signs in again with the Google provider using the same email, then surely the Google will not be duplicated for a second Google added as the third item of the list, something like this: `[Google, Facebook, Google]`.

Comment: it is already answered at [firebase-flutter-get-platform-user-used-to-sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253398/firebase-flutter-get-platform-user-used-to-sign-in)

Comment: @Rainysidewalks: the `providerData` contains all providers associated with the account, while OP here seems to want the provider that was used to sign in to the current session. That cannot be determined from the `providerData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `providerData` on the user shows all providers associated with the current user. It does not contain duplicates, nor does it have any information on which of these providers was used to sign in on the current session.

The only way to determine the sign-in provider is when the user actively signs in, at which point the credentials that were used are part of the [`UserCredential` return value](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) you get from the `signInWith...` call. Of course, those are going to be the same credentials that you passed in to the call - so you can capture them there too.