# Firebase Auth provider id constants in Android/kotlin?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

On iOS we can easily retrieve the constants for the different provider ids cfr [What is the full list of provider id's for firebase.UserInfo.providerId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901153/what-is-the-full-list-of-provider-ids-for-firebase-userinfo-providerid)

However I don't see these constants for Android (Kotlin)?

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```
   import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
   import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider


   fun FirebaseUser.loginType(): LoginType {
        if (isAnonymous) {
            return LoginType.Anonymous
        }
        Log.debug("providerId: $providerId")
        Log.debug("EmailAuthProvider: ${EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID}")
        Log.debug("GoogleAuthProvider: ${GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID}")
        Log.debug("FacebookAuthProvider: ${FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID}")

        loop@ for (userInfo in providerData) {
            when (userInfo.providerId) {
                EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> return LoginType.Email
                GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> return LoginType.Google
                FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID -> return LoginType.Facebook
                else -> continue@loop
            }
        }
        return LoginType.Unknown
    }

    fun FirebaseUser.loggedInWith(): String {
        return when (loginType()) {
            LoginType.Anonymous -> "Anonymous"
            LoginType.Email -> email ?: "?"
            LoginType.Facebook -> "Facebook"
            LoginType.Google -> "Google"
            LoginType.Unknown -> "???"
        }
    }
```